# Toolbar moves off screen when I use adjustpan

Tags: android, android-edittext, toolbar, android-appcompat, adjustpan

I am using the toolbar like in this post of google developers ([appcompat-v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html))

It works perfectly except when I press my editText. I set in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

But when the keyboard goes under my editText, the toolbar moves off screen.

Any way to solve this?

EDIT: adjustResize is not working in Lollipop and Kitkat, in JB yes.

EDIT2: it is caused by:   when I set it true.

Comment: Why wouldn't `adjustResize` be working in Lollipop?

Comment: I dont know, the keyboard just appear, but it doesnt go under my edittext. Kitkat same problem.

Comment: When I set true this <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">, I get the problem.

Comment: I have always had problems trying to use translucent navigation and translucent themes with a soft keyboard. I don't know if there's a solution.

Comment: Quick solution... adjustPan :/

Answer (score 0):

Try adjustResize in your code. It should work fine.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```